# Max among duplicated rows in R

Tags: r

I have a data set including several variables such as ID,Time,Age, v1,v 2, v3.
I need to replace the duplicated rows (condition on ID and time);  for the rows which have the same ID and time, get the max for each variable and replace it in the data set (I need to keep all the duplicated rows). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: please attempt it yourself

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(ID, time) %>%
  mutate_each(funs = funs(max)))
```

If you have NA values, try

```
your_data %>%
  group_by(ID, time) %>%
  mutate_each(funs = funs(max(., na.rm = T)))
```

Happy to test/demo on any data provided.

Comment: I must need to update my packages... couldn't find `%>%`, which looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

My example has only v1 and v2, but you get the idea...

```
> head(d)
  ID Time Age v1 v2
1  a    1  11 12 13
2  a    1  21 12 53
3  a    1  11 42 43
4  b    1   4  6  7
5  b    2   1  2  3
```

Here we aggregate to get the max

```
> agg = aggregate(
          list(Age=d$Age,v1=d$v1,v2=d$v2),
          by=list(ID=d$ID,Time=d$Time),
          FUN=max
        )

> head(agg)
  ID Time Age v1 v2
1  a    1  21 42 53
2  b    1   4  6  7
3  b    2   1  2  3
```

Now we merge that with the first two columns of our original data

```
> merge(d[,c(1,2)],agg,by=c("ID","Time"))
  ID Time Age v1 v2
1  a    1  21 42 53
2  a    1  21 42 53
3  a    1  21 42 53
4  b    1   4  6  7
5  b    2   1  2  3
```

Comment: I like the concept, but you could probably simplify it a little: `merge(dat[c("ID","Time")], aggregate(. ~ ID + Time, data=dat, FUN=max))`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `ave`, as applied to @Larsenal's example data:

```
idvars <- c("ID","Time")
numvars <- setdiff(names(dat), idvars)
dat[numvars] <- lapply(dat[numvars], function(x) ave(x, dat[idvars], FUN=max))

#  ID Time Age v1 v2
#1  a    1  21 42 53
#2  a    1  21 42 53
#3  a    1  21 42 53
#4  b    1   4  6  7
#5  b    2   1  2  3
```